# wordpress loop adding junk

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I'm having an issue with loops in Wordpress - code is being added on and repeated with the loop...

This is the code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'partials/loop', 'page' ); ?>

<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3' ); ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );?>

<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_excerpt()) ?>
```

```
<?php endwhile; else : ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'missing' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

The output:

```
<img width="100" height="100" src="http://blahblah/glasses-150x150.png" class="attachment-100x100 wp-post-image" alt="glasses">
<h4><a href="http://blahblah/titleofpost/">Title of Post</a></h4>
The Excerpt of the post, blah blah blah  Read more » 

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
```

I have no idea where the & nbsp; code at the end is coming from - any help appreciated :)

is coming from

Comment: Do you have any plugins that are attempting to add content to the bottom of the post? It seems like this might be a plugin issue. Try disabling them all and see if it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen in each post in the loop ?

Otherwise I think you should double check your html tab in your articles editing admin panel. The tinyMCE plugin often add some `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space character) when you hit enter to begin another line.